# Is there some effects on table's id index if error occured in transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Here's my main code of transaction in Yii 1.1:

```php
try{
     $transaction=Yii::app()->projectdb->beginTransaction();
     foreach($list as $order){
         $orderInfo = OrderInfo::model()->findByPk($order['order_id']); 
         if(empty($orderInfo )){
             throw new Exception('Empty order_info');
          }
       // ...
       // save order data into mysql

         }
      $transaction->commit();

   }catch (Exception $e){
       $transaction->rollBack();
    }
```

Now, I find there are missed ids in my table order,

```
select id from order where id between 10231 and 10280

# id      name 
# 10231   name_10231
# 10280   name_10280

# missed 50 data
```

Is this related to the transaction code above? When error happended within the transaction it will add id's index ?

Thanks very much if you can give me a clear answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it may be related to rollbacked transaction. If you're inserting new record during transaction, MySQL reserves ID for this record (increases `AUTO_INCREMENT` counter, so different processes may insert records during this transaction without risk of ID collision). This ID will not be reused, if you rollback transaction. So in case you:

1. open transaction,
2. insert 50 records,
3. rollback transaction,

you will end up with gap in IDs column, since these 50 IDs were reserved, but never committed.

Comment: thanks for your replying, more question. Is it different where the error happened? I mean if the error happened before `model->save()` operation, I catch it and rollback,  it is there still auto_increase of ID?

Comment: No, counter is increased by `INSERT` query, which is performed inside of `save()`.